# tex4ht corrupts "--" inside CDATA in the HTML file

Tags: luatex, tex4ht, make4ht

I am using an outside javascript package ([syntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/installation.html)) for code formatting when I compile to HTML that requires one to put code inside `<![CDATA[ ...  code .. ]]>` as explained in the above link

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This causes no problem, except that tex4ht for some reason changes `--` (two dashes) to something strange which causes syntaxHighlighter to fail rendering it, since it does not show on the screen, which is wrong.

Here is a MWE, and I show the command used and the final HTML, one can see clearly that `--` has been changed. This should not happen. Anything inside `<![CDATA[ ...  code .. ]]>` should not be touched by tex4ht as this is plain verbatim code and should be left as is. It is means to be used by the Javascript library.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}% 
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{\usepackage{luatex85}}{}

\ifdefined\HCode% detect tex4ht
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\else
\usepackage{fontspec}
\fi

\begin{document}    
\ifdefined\HCode
{\ScriptEnv{html}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\NoFonts\hfill\break}{\EndNoFonts\endgraf}
\begin{html}
<DIV><style scoped>.syntaxhighlighter {font-size: normalsize!important;}</style>
<script type="syntaxhighlighter"class="brush:bash; toolbar: false;" >
<![CDATA[
  make4ht --lua -u -c my.cfg -e main.mk4 foo.tex "htm,pic-align,notoc*"
]]>
</script>
</DIV>
\end{html}}
\else 
test
\fi

\end{document}
```

Compiled using  `make4ht --lua foo7_1.tex`  and this is how the HTML looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<!--http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd-->  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<!-- xhtml,html --> 
<meta name="src" content="foo7_1.tex" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foo7_1.css" /> 
</head><body 
>
<DIV><style scoped>.syntaxhighlighter {font-size: normalsize!important;}</style>
<script type="syntaxhighlighter"class="brush:bash; toolbar: false;" >
<![CDATA[
  make4ht lua -u -c my.cfg -e main.mk4 foo.tex "htm,pic-align,notoc*"
]]>
</script>
</DIV>


</body></html>
```

Notice the `--` are not displayed any more. They are changed to some non-displayable code. Here is screen shot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What do I need to change to make tex4ht not change code inside my HTML like this?  Please note that when you compile the above to HTML on your computer, nothing will display, since one needs the javascript package installed. But by viewing the source, one can see the problem.

A hex dump of the HTML shows that `--` was changed to hex 15

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which from the ascii table it is `NAK` (negative acknowledge)

---

**Update**

This problem happens for any data, even in `<PRE> ... </PRE>` and has nothing to do with `CDATA`. It seems tex4ht simply does not like to see `--` when in `lualatex` mode. Here is a new MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}% 
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{\usepackage{luatex85}}{}

\ifdefined\HCode% detect tex4ht
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\else
\usepackage{fontspec}
\fi

\begin{document}    
\ifdefined\HCode
{\ScriptEnv{html}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\NoFonts\hfill\break}{\EndNoFonts\endgraf}
\begin{html}
<PRE>
-- this is a test
</PRE>
\end{html}}
\else 
test
\fi

\end{document}
```

Same problem. Here is the HTML generated after `make4ht --lua foo.tex`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If I do not NOT compile using lualatex mode, then it works! And I get `--` show up in HTML.  i.e. if I compile the above using `make4ht foo.tex`, here is the HTML

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now the `--` are there. So this is a problem with lualatex mode with tex4ht.

Comment: unrelated to tex but that `<!CDATA` is an HTML:/Javascript syntax error (although the browser typically might be forgiving and not report it)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am sorry, I am not following you. Where is the syntax error?

Comment: `<script><![CDATA[` is a javascript syntax error in html. (It would be valid in xhtml, but I doubt you are serving your pages as XML rather than text/html)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that is what the documenation says to do as I have indicated in the link above? I am following the exact syntax of the package as documented. if the syntax is wrong, then the javascript library I am using would not have worked at all. But it works? and it does format all the code.

Comment: oh well OK I suppose the script is not being used for script as it has a made up type so it's just being used for data, in which case the `<![CDATA[` isn't marking a CDATA section but just literally making those characters in the input data which is strange but if that's what it wants.... (what happens if it isn't there?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle as I just updated the question, the data is corrupted even when using <PRE>....</PRE> so this has nothing to do with CDATA or the javascript library. tex4ht simply has a bug. I made bug report now on this. This is big problem for me. It means all the code formating I have does not work, since I have to use lualatex.

Comment: Extra info: vi shows the corrupted character as `^U` which is ascii control code 21 (0x15) in case that's of any use to anyone. I don't know why it's happening. I did wonder if it was trying to interpret `--` as an en-dash but `---` is converted to `^U-` in the html file.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot surprisingly enough vi is right:-)  (21 is endash in T1 encoding) the issue is the normal verbatim active character ligarture supression isn't woring in luatex as called by maek4ht

Comment: I think that problem is shown only inside the environment defined by `\ScriptEnv`.  The hyphen is made active and expands to `\string-\relax`, see `latex.4ht`.

Comment: @michal.h21 aha... `\relax` isn't enough to suppress ligatures in luatex as they happen later in the processing after `\relax` has gone, you might need \hbox{} or similar

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, I've added `\hbox{}` and it works nicely

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hyphen character is made active by `\ScriptEnv` command, which means that it calls a command when it is encountered in the environment defined with it. The `ScriptEnv` definition is little bit cryptic:

```
 \bgroup
  \catcode`\-=13
  \catcode`\(=1   \catcode`\)=2  \catcode`\/=0
  \catcode`\{=12   \catcode`\}=12  \catcode`\\=12
/gdef/ScriptEnv#1(%
   /expandafter/let/csname :#1:/endcsname=/empty
   /edef/:temp(/def/expandafter/noexpand/csname a:#1/endcsname
      ####1/expandafter/noexpand/csname end/endcsname{#1}%
      (####1/noexpand/:EndVerbatim/noexpand/end(#1)))/:temp
%   /expandafter/def/csname
%      b:#1/endcsname##1\end{#1}(##1/:EndVerbatim/end(#1))%
   /expandafter/def/csname
      b:#1/endcsname(/bgroup /catcode`/-=13
     /def/:temp####1\end{#1}(/egroup
         /def-(/string-/relax)
         ####1/:EndVerbatim%
         /expandafter/def/csname end#1/endcsname()%
         /end(#1))%
     /:temp)%
   /edef/:temp(/noexpand/DefScript:
      /expandafter/noexpand/csname #1/endcsname
      (/expandafter/noexpand/csname a:#1/endcsname)%
      (/expandafter/noexpand/csname b:#1/endcsname))/:temp
)
/egroup
```

the important line is:

```
/def-(/string-/relax)
```

it seems that under LuaTeX, two consecutive hyphens forms `endash` in this case, which is not translated to unicode character for some reason, but remains in 8-bit encoding. I don't really understand it, but the solution is to alter the `\ScriptEnv` definition to suppress the ligature forming:

```
\bgroup
  \gdef\:scriptenv:breakhyphen{\hbox{}}
  \catcode`\-=13
  \catcode`\(=1   \catcode`\)=2  \catcode`\/=0
  \catcode`\{=12   \catcode`\}=12  \catcode`\\=12
/gdef/ScriptEnv#1(%
   /expandafter/let/csname :#1:/endcsname=/empty
   /edef/:temp(/def/expandafter/noexpand/csname a:#1/endcsname
      ####1/expandafter/noexpand/csname end/endcsname{#1}%
      (####1/noexpand/:EndVerbatim/noexpand/end(#1)))/:temp
%   /expandafter/def/csname
%      b:#1/endcsname##1\end{#1}(##1/:EndVerbatim/end(#1))%
   /expandafter/def/csname
      b:#1/endcsname(/bgroup /catcode`/-=13
     /def/:temp####1\end{#1}(/egroup
         /def-(/string-/:scriptenv:breakhyphen/relax)
         ####1/:EndVerbatim%
         /expandafter/def/csname end#1/endcsname()%
         /end(#1))%
     /:temp)%
   /edef/:temp(/noexpand/DefScript:
      /expandafter/noexpand/csname #1/endcsname
      (/expandafter/noexpand/csname a:#1/endcsname)%
      (/expandafter/noexpand/csname b:#1/endcsname))/:temp
)
/egroup
```

correct the definition in local copy of `latex.4ht`. I will update the `tex4ht` sources.

Comment: thank you. I changed latex.4ht as you have and now the `--` show up!  I have no idea how you understand the above code and what it all means. It is really scary looking. Thanks again.

Comment: @Nasser I don't really understand it, I only know that `\def-` influences hyphens :)